# jquery getting data when click on specfic div,i want that when we click on Ajax 1 then

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want that when we click on Ajax 1 then content of ajax1 is change but Ajax 2 will remain same and vice verse plz help i want to do that with jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pas").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"001.php?q=1 & l=111", success:function(result){
    $("#pas").html(result);
  }});
});});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pas"><h2>AJAX 1</h2></div>
<div id="pas"><h2> AJAX2 </h2></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look up the jQuery "context" attribute.. In with your "url" attribute, put 'contect:this', then when the success function is called, "this" will refer to the div that was clicked on. :)

Comment: I am very confused as to what needs to happen? Are you saying that when you click on a certain element to initiate an AJAX request, you only want the content of THAT specific element to update (or at least a child of it) and nothing else? Please clarify a little more. Thanks.

Comment: How do you expect this to work with the same ID on both elements ?

Answer (score 2):

Two elements cannot have the same `id`. You should change to using classes.

```
<div class="pas"><h2>AJAX 1</h2></div>
<div class="pas"><h2> AJAX2 </h2></div>
```

Once you've done that, you can use `this` to target the correct item.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pas").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);    // "this" is the clicked element

        $.ajax({url:"001.php?q=1 & l=111", success:function(result){
            $this.html(result);
        }});
    });
});
```

Comment: crap, just deleted my answer, you beat me by seconds there James! +1.

Comment: if i am getting comments on topic ,and comments is getting from database in div id=pas ,i want that when user click on 12th comment then display result on 12th this div

Answer (score 1):

you have to differentiate div's ids: give them two different id (i.e. pas1 and pas2 ) and same class 'pas', then fire actions on div.pas

Comment: if i remove id of div,when user click on div content wil change <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pas").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"001.php?q=1 & l=111", success:function(result){
    $("#pas").html(result);
  }});
});});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pas"><h2>AJAX 1</h2></div>
<div id="pas"><h2> AJAX2 </h2></div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Don't use duplicated id's, use class instead. Use a refference to the clicked object to update your content. Here is your modified code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").click(function(){
  var _this = this;
  $.ajax({url:"001.php?q=1 & l=111", success:function(result){
    $(_this).html(result);
  }});
});});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><h2>AJAX 1</h2></div>
<div><h2> AJAX2 </h2></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok frz i am geting all div which is fetching from databse content ,how can i generate automatic id

Comment: friends if i am getting coomments on topic ,and comments is getting from database in div id=pas ,i want that when user click on 12th comment then display result on this div

Comment: no i will try this,when i am free but i am asking u another question if i remove class of div,when user click on div content will change

Comment: sir when i click on ajax 1 it will removed and not getting content plz tell  me

Comment: sir it contain simple html text